# find application position relative to screen point macOS swift

Tags: swift, macos

Trying to find applications current position in X Y coordinate. For example: An application has starting point(X,Y) + Hight, Width. How to find its starting point as CGPoint or X Y onscreen values?

Current trying with `view.bounds` :

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

var testPoint = CGPoint.zero;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //testPoint = view.bounds.height //rect
    //if possible following:
   //testPoint =  CGPoint(x: view.window?.frame.origin.x , y: view.window?.frame.origin.y) 
    print(testPoint)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` ask the `window` of the `view` for the `origin` of its `frame`

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    print(view.window?.frame.origin)
}
```

Comment: Since `view.window?.frame.origin` is nil on viewDidLoad, Is there any way to get the origin/anything for x,y coordinates dynamically, on a event such as a button click?

Comment: What is wrong with `viewWillAppear`? You can get the point whenever the window is available.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow) API, particularly [NSWindow.frameRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419372-framerect).